# Write same color buffer in different sub-passes of the render pass

Tags: vulkan

I wrote a VkRenderPass. There are two color and depth attachment VkAttachmentDescriptions and we note they are C0, C1, D0, and D1. I list the details of each VkAttachmentDescription as follows:

```
C0 : LoadOp clear, StoreOp Store.
D0 : LoadOp clear, StoreOp Store.
C1 : LoadOp load, StoreOp Store.
D1 : LoadOp load, StoreOp Store.
```

And I wrote two sub-passes for this VkRenderPass, the first sub-pass (note SP1) use C0 as color attachment and D0 as depth attachment. The second sub-pass (note SP2) use C1 as color attachment and D1 as depth attachment. The VkSubPassDependency between SP1 and SP2 describe as follows :

```
srcPipelineStage : Bottom.
dstPipelineStage : Top
```

It means draw commands in SP2 need wait SP1 finished. I try to avoid write-after-write hazard.(I’m not sure it’s correct usage or not?)

Now let us see my render flow.

Firstly, I have two VkImages, one is used as color buffer(note Cb). Another is used as depth buffer(note Db).

Secondly, I wrote four VkImageViews for bind the color and depth buffer for VkFrameBuffer(note FB). I specify the four ImageViews as follows :

```
ImageView 0 bind with color buffer Cb.
ImageView 1 bind with depth buffer Db.
ImageView 2 bind with color buffer Cb.
ImageView 3 bind with depth buffer Db.
```

And then, the draw flow are list as follow :

```
BeginRenderPass with FB( current is SP0)
vkCmdDraw for quad1. (we call this C00)
vkCmdDraw for quad2. (we call this C01)
vkCmdNextRenderPass (current should be SP1)
vkCmdDraw for quad1. (we call this C00)
vkCmdDraw for quad2. (we call this C01)
EndRenderPass
```

Finally, I can see the result is my expect. But I have some questions about this rendering flow.

The first is about multiple sub-passes. I found some informations and they tell me that the execution between sub-passes are asyncheonization. Is it real?

If it’s real(command execution is asynchronization between sub-passes), the second question is coming.

The pipeline stages of the draw commands in same sub-pass progress are step-by-steps?

For example, C00 and C01 are draw cmds in SP0. Is the execution about C00 and C01 like this :

```
SP0 => C00 TOP -> C01 TOP -> C00 VERTEX INPUT -> C01 VERTEX INPUT -> C00 VERTEX SHADER -> C01 VERTEX SHADER -> … C00 BOTTOM -> C01 BOTTOM.
```

(Because I think it should execute by the steps in this example, thus VkSubPassDependency be able to use for synchronizing sub-passes.)

They are my two question.

B.R.

Comment: Your question is confused. You're not writing to the same color buffer from different subpasses. So what exactly are you asking about?

Comment: That's a lot of intro text for two relatively simple questions.

Comment: @NicolBolas Hi, I say I write the same color buffer from different subpasses because I bind a VkImage to two ImageView they are used in SP1 and SP2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

Yes, as mostly everything in Vulkan, subpasses are asynchronous to each other. Any kind of synchronization is given only explicitly by those Subpass Dependencies.

For completeness, "asynchronous" means no timing is specified between the subpasses. They might be executed serially, reordered, in paralel, preempted, or anything in between. The drivers choice.

2.

In a single subpass output attachments of draw commands are synchronized implicitly\automatically (one of about two exceptions the specification makes for sanity). This is called Rasterization Order. And it respects Primitive Order, meaning the triangles of the second draw will be on top of the triangles of the first draw.

Anything else needs explicit synchronization.

TOP of all commands does technically execute in ordrer. Though "execute" is bit of a misnomer. The stage does nothing.

Your stage order is only one of many possible ones. Another conformant order would be e.g. all stages on C00 -> all stages on C01. Though that is a highly theoretical difference. For it to matter we would have to observe some side-effect of this, which I can't imagine being possible.

The Subpass Dependency works either way, so not sure how the two questions relate. When you mean all stages, I suggest using ALL instead of TOP or BOTTOM; much more readable and less error-prone.

Comment: If the real execution are following stages on C00 -> all stages on C01, how to synchorization commands execution in different sub-passes via subpass dependency? (For example, when we execute C00 to fragment stage at SP1, C10 are executed, but the result I want is all commands in SP1 need to wait all command in SP0 finished.)

Comment: My point is the order of stages in the single subpass does not matter. The counterexample was meant to disabuse you of the notion that any specific stage order is the "real" one. Your subpass Dependency says that if all commands in SP0 have not finished at least `srcStage`, then no commands in SP1 are allowed to reach `dstStage`. How stages are performed in a single subpass across two commands does not matter at all for this to work.